# Trouble opening the MFMailComposeViewController on the device, works in simulator. 

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am doing this its working in simulator but when we try to open in device then program is terminating.

Plz suggess me fast.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
mail.mailComposeDelegate=self;  
[mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"marketing@realestateinvestar.com.au",nil]];

//[self becomeFirstResponder];
mail.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok, but did you check  if the device can send mail:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendText]) {
   MFMailComposeViewController *mail=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
   mail.mailComposeDelegate=self;  
   [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"marketing@realestateinvestar.com.au",nil]];

   mail.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   [self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];
   [mail release], mail = nil;
} else {
    // show message to the use that he can't send an email.
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it again terminate in device but not in simulator.

Comment: Please supply the error message, iOS version of the device and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implement MFMailComposeViewControllerdelegate methods in your code??

```
#pragma mark --------------------------------------------
#pragma mark MFMailComposeViewController delegate Methods

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (result) {  
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:  
            NSLog(@"Mail send canceled.");  
            /* 
             Execute your code for canceled event here ... 
             */  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:  
            NSLog(@"Mail saved.");  
            /* 
             Execute your code for email saved event here ... 
             */  
            break;  
        case MFMailComposeResultSent: {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Sent" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            alert.tag = 1;
            alert.delegate = self;
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            break;  
        }
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed: {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mail Sending Failed" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            alert.tag = 2;
            alert.delegate = self;
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            break;  
        }
        default:  
            break;  
    }
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];//dismissing modal view controller
}
```

Comment: have u checked it? [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
```

Your problem is here. You are trying to check whether device will be able to send Text messages and not email Message. you should try using

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
```

The problem might be that your device is not configured to any accounts in the mail.Please check this once.

Comment: Download the sample code from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865 and see if this works on the device.